# Jena Fuseki ontology accepted but not viewable

Tags: webserver, sparql, owl, rdfs, fuseki

So we are supposed to set up a "`web Server`" ontology on fuseki and access it via `nodejs`. 
I created the dataset "data" and added my ontology via `xml`. Fuseki accepted it . This is the ontology :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
         xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
         xmlns:ns0="http://localhost:3000/data#">

  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://localhost:3000/data#message">
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>

  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://localhost:3000/data#firstname">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#ObjectProperty"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>

  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://localhost:3000/data#lastname">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#ObjectProperty"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>

  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://localhost:3000/data#linkeddata">
    <rdfs:comment>The class of all data types.</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:label>The data type</rdfs:label>
  </owl:Class>

  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://localhost:3000/data#users">
    <rdfs:comment>Users that post Tweets.</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:label>Users</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://localhost:3000/data#linkeddata"/>
  </owl:Class>

  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://localhost:3000/data#tweets">
    <rdfs:comment>Tweets contain messages of Users.</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:label>Tweets</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://localhost:3000/data#linkeddata"/>
  </owl:Class>

  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://localhost:3000/data#tweetedby">
  </owl:ObjectProperty>

  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://localhost:3000/data#1234">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://localhost:3000/data#tweets"/>
    <ns0:message>blablubbtweet</ns0:message>
    <ns0:tweetedby>
      <ns0:users rdf:about="http://localhost:3000/data#2345">
        <ns0:firstname>Manuel</ns0:firstname>
        <ns0:lastname>Neuer</ns0:lastname>
      </ns0:users>
    </ns0:tweetedby>

  </rdf:Description>

</rdf:RDF>
```

I hope you can see that I created the classes "**users**" , "**tweets**" and "**linkeddata**" . 
If I try view the data on the Fuseki server with the endpoint "/data/query" with following code its says "no data in table". Im expecting 27 Triples...what am I overlooking ?

```
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?class ?label ?description
WHERE {
?class a owl:class.
OPTIONAL { ?class rdfs:label ?label}
OPTIONAL { ?class rdfs:comment ?description}
}
```

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? (I see no SQL there.)

Comment: Select Distinct Where ?!

Comment: Is that an SQL attempt? Thought it was some fancy new language... Well, then keep the <sql> tag.

Comment: `owl:Class`, not `owl:class`, I guess.

Comment: I tried that in the Sparql Endpoint query, it yields the same result. Thank you nontheless.

Comment: the obvious question is, how exactly did you load the data into Fuseki? And which config file did you use to start Fuseki. And clearly, for debugging, `SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o}` to see if there is any data in the default graph of the running Fuseki.

Comment: And guys, this is **not** SQL ...

Comment: Sparql uses Sql semantics....

Comment: I loaded the data into Fuseki with the xml. It should generate the test user "Manuel Neuer" as you can see in the file above. I tried the other Statement but it doesnt show anthing.

Comment: I did not change anything in the config.ttl. 
Actually my teammate impelemented this solution on Linux and sent me the Fuseki files. But since it threw an error on windows when trying to open it, I decided to set it up manually.

Comment: Try `SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o}` as suggested followed by `SELECT * WHERE {?s a ?o}` If you get nothing, then try: `SELECT * WHERE { GRAPH ?g { ?s ?p ?o}}`

Comment: Thank you Andy, the last suggestion it is !
Have a nice evening !

Comment: @Bitlord *"Sparql uses Sql semantics.... "* - aha, ok. I didn't know this. Thank you

Comment: @Bitlord - _Sparql uses Sql semantics...._  Not really. SPARQL did model a chunk of its syntactical structure on SQL, but the syntax *and* semantic differences start early and go deep.

Comment: As you said and the name implies its based on sql. I dont know whats ur point.Sparql and sql are both jut models of SEMANTIC structures if you want to expreess it like that.